# Database Multiple select Query , Unable to Retrieve Desired Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, join

I have three Tables as given below , I want to search record on base of three Different cafeterias in Single query,I want to search record whether user give `Brand_Name , Drug_Id, Generic Name` It give same output I.E. `all record of That Drug_ID` ,I am new to Database, however i think i solved it using `Multiple select queries` but it takes Too Much time

I Searched & find That Joins are faster , so i tried to use it , But never Get exact answer,

- How to solve scenario Using Multiple Select query Efficitly
- Can it be solved using Joins , If yes then how, if not then why not

  ```
  Table: Company_List ([Company_ID],[Company_Name],[Company_Address],[Company_Contact],[Company_Website],[Company_Fax])

  Table: Drugs_List ([Drug_ID],[Generic_Name],[Dosage_Form],[Max_Course],[Drug_Type],[Adult_Dosage],[Paediatric_Dosage_20Kg],[Neonatal_Dosage_3Kg],[Frequency])

  Table: Drug_Details ([Company_ID],[Drug_ID],[Brand_Name],[Package_Size],[Price])
  ```

> Working (But Tacking too much Time)

```
 SELECT distinct(Company_List.Company_Name),
 Drug_Details.* 
 from Drug_Details , Company_List,Drugs_List 
 where Drug_Details.Company_ID=Company_List.Company_ID And 
 ( 
 Drug_Details.Drug_ID ='arnica' OR 
 Brand_Name Like '%arnica%' OR
 Drugs_List.Generic_Name Like '%arnica%'
 and(Drugs_List.Drug_ID=Drug_Details.Drug_ID)
 );
```

Output:[image]

> Translate into inner join (Not working)

```
 SELECT distinct(Company_List.Company_Name),
Drug_Details.* 
from Drug_Details , Company_List
INNER JOIN Drugs_List
ON Drug_ID=Drugs_List.Drug_ID
where Drug_Details.Company_ID=Company_List.Company_ID And
(Drug_Details.Drug_ID ='arnica' OR 
 Brand_Name Like '%arnica%')
```

output: [image]

```
 select * from Drugs_List where Generic_Name like'%arnica%'
```

Output:[image: Result of First Query]

```
select * from Drug_Details where Brand_Name like'%arnica%'
```

Output:[image: Result of second Query]

```
 select * from Drug_Details where Drug_ID='a0927'
```

Output: [image: Result Of 3rd Query]

Comment: Actually Your  **Working (But Tacking too much Time)** Even doesn't work  as you desired, if brand name doesn't match given criteria

Comment: You are Right I checked , & it isn't working if brand name Changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this kind of scenario

1. Retrieve Drug_ID from Given Criteria (`Brand_Name , Drug_Id, Generic Name`)
2. Select Record on base of That `Retrieved Drug_ID`

---

```
 SELECT distinct(Company_List.Company_Name),
 Drug_Details.* 
 from Drug_Details , Company_List 
 where Company_List.Company_ID=Drug_Details.Company_ID and Drug_Details.Drug_ID in 
(
   select distinct(Drug_Details.Drug_ID) from Drug_Details where Drug_Details.Brand_Name like '%arnica%' or Drug_Details.Drug_ID in 
        (
          select Distinct(Drugs_List.Drug_ID) from Drugs_List where Generic_Name like '%arnica%' or Drugs_List.Drug_ID='arnica'
        ) 
 )
```

> Most Inner Query

```
select Distinct(Drugs_List.Drug_ID) from Drugs_List where Generic_Name like '%arnica%' or Drugs_List.Drug_ID='arnica'
```

Retrive all `Drug_Id's` from `Drug_List` Table If Given Criteria Matches with `Generic_Name` OR `Drug_ID`

Result: A0925,A0926,A0927,A0928,A0929,B0271

> Middle Inner Query

```
select distinct(Drug_Details.Drug_ID) from Drug_Details where Drug_Details.Brand_Name like '%arnica%' or Drug_Details.Drug_ID in 
    (
      select Distinct(Drugs_List.Drug_ID) from Drugs_List where Generic_Name like '%arnica%' or Drugs_List.Drug_ID='arnica'
    ) 

//Query as given below

select distinct(Drug_Details.Drug_ID) from Drug_Details where Drug_Details.Brand_Name like '%arnica%' or Drug_Details.Drug_ID in 
        (
           'A0925','A0926','A0927','A0928','A0929','B0271'
        )
```

Result: A0927

Retrieve Selected Drug_Id If Given Criteria Matches with `Generic_Name` OR `Drug_ID` Or `Brand Name`

> Most Outer Query

```
SELECT distinct(Company_List.Company_Name),
     Drug_Details.* 
     from Drug_Details , Company_List 
     where Company_List.Company_ID=Drug_Details.Company_ID and Drug_Details.Drug_ID in 
    (
       select distinct(Drug_Details.Drug_ID) from Drug_Details where Drug_Details.Brand_Name like '%arnica%' or Drug_Details.Drug_ID in 
            (
              select Distinct(Drugs_List.Drug_ID) from Drugs_List where Generic_Name like '%arnica%' or Drugs_List.Drug_ID='arnica'
            ) 
     )

//Query as given

 SELECT distinct(Company_List.Company_Name),
 Drug_Details.* 
 from Drug_Details , Company_List 
 where Company_List.Company_ID=Drug_Details.Company_ID and Drug_Details.Drug_ID in 
( 
 'A0927'
 )
```

Result : Retrieve record against

`Company ID :1 , Drug_ID : A0927 
Company ID :9 , Drug_ID : A0927`